# Does OS matter?

Tags: video, youtube-dl

Using a computer, I am downloading videos from youtube using YTD and converting videos to mp3 tru google. Then, I am copying it using a flashdrive and transfering the files on my laptop. But on my laptop, I cannot play everything even if I duplicated the videos in different file formats. My pc is Windows 7 while my laptop is Windows 8. Does OS matter?

One time, my files on my flashdrive was converted into hundreds of folders w/ special characters.

Comment: How do you convert your videos ? Wich codecs do you have on wich OS? In shortly OS doesnt metter, but codecs does!

Comment: so you can't play the video's? tried vlc player? http://www.videolan.org or is the mp3 the problem?

Comment: i tried playing it using vlc, wmp and chrome. but it always says "cannot open the file and so on." Im converting the files using Any video Converter

Comment: Wich file you can play on windows 7 and cannot play on 8? I will asume that you are useing VLC.

Comment: The one i downloaded and the file converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the video codec that matters, not the OS.
If you save a movie in a format, certain codecs will be able to decode/play it.
In order for it to work on the target OS, the corresponding codecs must be installed there.